# Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw for module r8169 with 2.6.38 kernel

Tags: 10.10, kernel, realtek, initramfs, firmware

I notice when I do:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

With the latest kernel release (2.6.38) I get the following warning messages:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-3-generic-pae
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw for module r8169
```

How can I resolve this problem?

***Dean Thomson Feb 14 at 4:11 wrote:***

> Unfortunately, the linux-firmware package isn't for **Maverick**.

Answer (score 5):

I just fixed the problem by downloading firmware-linux-realtek from Debian.

first, let's make sure you still have the problem:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Now, if you still see the errors get the package:

```
cd && wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-realtek_0.28_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite firmware-realtek_0.28_all.deb
```

Let's verify the solution:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

If everything goes well, you won't see the messages :)

Comment: This method worked for me on LinuxMint 12 also.  Neither the linux-firmware nor linux-firmware-nonfree packages contained the rtl8168f* firmware files, but the debian package does.  Note that the current package is firmware-realtek_0.36_all.deb and the 0.28_all package has been removed (though there is a 0.28 package with squeeze in the name).

Comment: I guess the actual deb packages are subject to change.  The following was the most recent when I followed the method above firmware-realtek_20190717-2_all.deb

Comment: The deb packages mentioned were not there for me, however a simple:
"sudo apt install firmware-realtek" installed it and then the update-initramfs no longer reported missing firmware.
Debian testing (bullseye)

Comment: Same as installing manually the last one from http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/ Now it's called `firmware-realtek_20230210-4~bpo11+1_all.deb`.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this PPA... it has updated firmware packages:

- https://launchpad.net/~chasedouglas/+archive/linux-firmware
- https://launchpad.net/~chasedouglas/+archive/linux-firmware-nonfree

The missing files can be found in the `linux-firmware` package

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: Unfortunately, the linux-firmware package isn't for Maverick.

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved the same problem.

I have downloaded linux-firmware package from natty from page https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware and installed it manually:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/linux-firmware_1.49_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.49_all.deb
```

Then one should call

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

or, more conveniently

```
sudo aptitude reinstall linux-image-2.6.38-2.dmz.1-liquorix-686
```

(place your required kernel package here)

Warning seems to be gone, so all firmwares are on their proper places.

Answer (score 1):

First, check if r8169 is a loaded module (lsmod). If it is, use `modprobe -r r8169` or `rmmod r8169` to temporarily remove it and then install the new kernel or whatever you need to install. Afterward, use `modprobe r8169` to re-install the module.